# webpack on postinstall fails on loading typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, package

I have a package that I have built to run a postinstall webpack script. Literally as described in my package.json

```
"scripts": {       
   ...
   "postinstall": "webpack"
}
```

the webpack is as so:

```
const path = require('path');

const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = {
    target: "node",
    entry: {
        Core: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/Core.ts')
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: {
      filename: "[name].js",
      chunkFilename: "[name].js",
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    externals: {
        canvas: "commonjs canvas",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".ts"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    options:{
                        configFile: path.resolve(__dirname,"tsconfig.json")
                    }
                }],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    },
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    ],
};
```

When I am in the package and run the postscript it works fine. When I include the package in another project I get a typescript error and I'm not sure why. It is like the typescript loader `ts-loader` isn't working. Any idea why?

```
ERROR in ./src/Core.ts 32:0
Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (32:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I found out my issue. 
When my project loads in the npm package and the postinstall triggers, my npm package doesn't have a node_modules package readily available to use `ts-loader` etc.

So I had to resolve my loaders to scope to my project instead of my npm package. I'll post my new webpack config.

```
const path = require('path');

const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = {
    target: "node",
    entry: {
        Core: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/Core.ts')
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: {
      filename: "[name].js",
      chunkFilename: "[name].js",
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    externals: {
        canvas: "commonjs canvas",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".ts"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    options:{
                        configFile: path.resolve(__dirname,"tsconfig.json")
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../node_modules'), path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.vue', '.js'],
        mainFields: ['ts-loader', 'vue-loader', 'babel-loader']
    },
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    ],
};
```

Coming into webpack blind it was painful to figure it out, so I hope this helps others

Answer (score 0):

A bit more *defaulty*:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'my-module': './src/my-module.ts'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        // !! Do not exclude "my-module" from ts-loader
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!my-module)/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, '..'), // just the parent dir
      './node_modules', // normal node_modules
    ],
  },
};
```